# Solving a system of second order tightly coupled nonlinear ODE with six initial conditions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, scientific-computing, numerical-integration

I am solving a problem from fluid dynamics; in particular tightly coupled nonlinear ordinary differential equations. The following is a scaled-down version of my actual problem.
I have solved system of coupled odes many times in the past but this case is different since double derivatives of one variable depends on the double derivative of another variable. How do I implement it in ode45? I need 3 x 2  = 6 plots of x, x-dot and x-ddot versus time for t, 0 to 2. All required initial conditions have zero values.
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. If the ODEs had no last terms of double derivatives, I would have done it myself.

Comment: I think this question fits better on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Posted there, not of much help.

Comment: Or, can anyone please help me with the solution of a much simpler problem: https://postimg.cc/9z7LXg8B

Comment: Have you tried simply substituting the values for the second derivatives into the expressions? I suggest maybe trying a convenient change of variables, such as `u=(x_1+x_2)` and `v=(x_1-x_2)`.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you all so much for helping me fix this problem. :)